# Heavy Weapons for small Races

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, homebrew-review

In my upcoming 5e game I plan to homebrew the great weapon master feat to additionally remove the disadvantage that small creatures get when using heavy weapons. Do you think I should incorporate something to balance this or is it fine without any new penalties?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Make sure you take the [tour] if you haven't already, and visit [help] for more information.

Comment: To what end are you homebrewing this? Do you have a player who wants to play a small character with heavy weapons, or is it specifically for story reasons/NPCs?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Homebrewing a small character with a heavy weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69055/60441)

Comment: @TheLittlePeace It's for a player who wants to make fairy barbarian and I thought taking the great weapon master feat to be able to do so would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This does not meaningfully change the balance point of the game.

A player can simply select a medium race at character creation if they wish to use heavy weapons and the GWM feat to their full potential.  They lose nothing particularly relevant to heavy weapons or the GWM feat by doing so - Small races are not meaningfully advantaged compared to Medium races, and the penalty they suffer with heavy weapons does not translate into some sort of commensurate benefit.

### This may change the balance point of an existing PC or NPC.

If you have for example a Halfling Barbarian, GWM allowing smaller races to wield larger weapons more effectively will deeply improve their combat prospects.

However, given that a Small character relying on GWM/heavy weapons is going to typically struggle, this is likely to be a good thing for the overall balance of your game rather than a bad thing.

**Overall, the permanent disadvantage to small characters using heavy weapons is a fairly hamfisted attempt to force them away from using greataxes and the like, and removing it does nothing much other than allow people the flavour of being a small guy with a huge sword, which many people enjoy.**